# Prolog character stream error

Tags: prolog

My code is supposed to stop when it finds stop in the file its reading from, but its not. I keep getting an error:

```
% reads in a character and then checks whether this character is a blank,
% a carriage return or the end of the stream. In any of these cases a
% complete word has been read otherwise the next character is read.


calculate([stop],_) :- !.
calculate([],_):-!.
calculate([Word|Rest],X) :-
    word_to_number(Word,Symbol),
    concat(X,Symbol,NewX),
    calculate(Rest,NewX),
    atom_to_term(NewX,Eq,[]),
    print('Calculating '),print(NewX),print('  The result is: '),
    Result is Eq,
        print(Result),nl,
    execute.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that calculate is recursive. At some point, `calculate([one], '03+')` called, which in turn calls `calculate([], '03+1')`, which gives a result (4). It then invokes execute and processes the rest of the input.

*Then*, the calling calculate succeeds, and now goes on to applying `atom_to_term` to `'03+'`, which gives the error.

You can fix this by moving the conversion to an atom into a separate predicate:

```
to_atom([Word], Symbol) :- word_to_number(Word, Symbol).
to_atom([Word|Rest], Term) :-
    word_to_number(Word,Symbol),
    to_atom(Rest, Symbol2),
    concat(Symbol,Symbol2,Term).

...
calculate(List) :-
    to_atom(List, NewX),
    atom_to_term(NewX,Eq,[]),
    ...
```

Then you won't need the dummy 0 in the beginning, either.

Comment: Thank you so so much .. you cant imagine how much i am grateful to you .. i think i still dont get the recursion idea .. i will work on that now .. again thank you so much .. i greatly appreciate your help

Comment: It's indeed difficult to see what the problem is. I used `trace,test` to step through calculate, and suggest that you do, too.

Answer (score 2):

Declare "plus", "minus" and "times" as operators, and you can use read/1 to read Prolog terms directly, since the input is then valid Prolog syntax.

Comment: thanks for the advice .. i started reading on how to create operators but i was blessed with a tweak that fixed my code .. thanks alot for the response ..